# How to unscope a where clause on a joined ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

On my model MediaFileAsset, I have the following added via an included lib:

```
default_scope ->{eager_load(:service_asset_core).where(service_asset_cores: {archived: false})}
```

Leaving aside reasons to not use default_scopes, is there a way to use [unscope](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/unscope) to remove this scope from a query?

So, for example, maybe someone passes me

```
assets = MediaFileAsset.where(custom_conditions)
```

and I want to count all of these IGNORING the `archived` field on `service_asset_cores`. If `archived` were a field of `media_file_assets`, I could use

```
assets.unscope(where: :archived).count
```

But that doesn't work here because `archived` is a field on `ServiceAssetCore`, not `MediaFileAsset`.

Using `unscoped` and `unscope(:where)` work to remove the archived condition, but these remove more than just that condition, which is not quite what I'm looking for. I believe this is why the `unscope()` method was added in the first place, and I'm trying to learn if it's possible to use it to remove query conditions on joined tables.

For reference:

```
2.2.2 > MediaFileAsset.unscoped.count
   (505.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `media_file_assets`
 => 3078951
```

And to unscope just the specific where: :archived clause, I have tried:

```
2.2.2 > MediaFileAsset.unscope(where: {service_asset_cores: :archived}).count
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `media_file_assets`.`id`) FROM `media_file_assets` LEFT OUTER JOIN `service_asset_cores` ON `service_asset_cores`.`service_asset_id` = `media_file_assets`.`id` AND `service_asset_cores`.`service_asset_type` = 'MediaFileAsset' WHERE `service_asset_cores`.`archived` = 0
 => 10

2.2.2 > MediaFileAsset.all.merge(ActsAsServiceAsset::ServiceAssetCore.unscoped).count
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `media_file_assets`.`id`) FROM `media_file_assets` LEFT OUTER JOIN `service_asset_cores` ON `service_asset_cores`.`service_asset_id` = `media_file_assets`.`id` AND `service_asset_cores`.`service_asset_type` = 'MediaFileAsset' WHERE `service_asset_cores`.`archived` = 0
 => 10

2.2.2 > MediaFileAsset.unscope(where: :archived).count
   (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `media_file_assets`.`id`) FROM `media_file_assets` LEFT OUTER JOIN `service_asset_cores` ON `service_asset_cores`.`service_asset_id` = `media_file_assets`.`id` AND `service_asset_cores`.`service_asset_type` = 'MediaFileAsset' WHERE `service_asset_cores`.`archived` =
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `media_file_assets`.`id`) FROM `media_file_assets` LEFT OUTER JOIN `service_asset_cores` ON `service_asset_cores`.`service_asset_id` = `media_file_assets`.`id` AND `service_asset_cores`.`service_asset_type` = 'MediaFileAsset' WHERE `service_asset_cores`.`archived` =
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `media_file_assets`.`id`) FROM `media_file_assets` LEFT OUTER JOIN `service_asset_cores` ON `service_asset_cores`.`service_asset_id` = `media_file_assets`.`id` AND `service_asset_cores`.`service_asset_type` = 'MediaFileAsset' WHERE `service_asset_cores`.`archived` =

2.2.2 > MediaFileAsset.all.merge(ActsAsServiceAsset::ServiceAssetCore.unscope(where: :archived)).count
# output omitted, same error as pervious
```

That last two seem like a Rails (4.2.3) bug since the SQL generated is invalid. Maybe this is where I need to be but the bug is in my way. Is there another method I should be trying, or am I stuck with the horrors of the unavoidable default_scope?

Comment: I've never used `unscoped`, but maybe `unscoped.where(service_asset_cores: :archived)`

Comment: Won't work unfortunately. unscoped removes all previously attached scopes and query methods. unscope(*args) can remove specific queries, but I can't get it to remove queries on joined models, and there's the question.

Comment: Ah, I meant to sat `unscope` not `unscoped`, but that still doesn't work I guess. If there is any way to remove the default scope that would be the way to go, but I assume you have other considerations preventing that...

Comment: Yup. The lib will be included in tens of models that are pervasive, and there's a heavy preference among the dev team as a whole to not have to specify something like "active" as an explicit scope everywhere since most other devs are not interested in archived assets. I am trying to keep them around to analyze errors and other failures, but I have to do so transparently to other devs' concerns. One possible solution is to ditch the service_asset_cores table and add the columns to each model that include the module, but that's (a) a lot of migration, and (b) less robust to structural changes.

Answer (score 1):

#### Unscope column on specified table (Rails 6.1+)

Starting from Rails 6.1, it is possible to unscope only the column in the specified table.

```rb
posts = Post.joins(:comments).group(:"posts.hidden")
posts = posts.where("posts.hidden": false, "comments.hidden": false)

posts.count
# => { false => 10 }

# unscope both hidden columns
posts.unscope(where: :hidden).count
# => { false => 11, true => 1 }

# unscope only comments.hidden column
posts.unscope(where: :"comments.hidden").count
# => { false => 11 }
```

Here is [a link to the corresponding PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/39172).

So, I suppose, the following can solve your problem:

```rb
MediaFileAsset.unscope(where: :"service_asset_cores.archived").where(custom_conditions)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close.

MediaFileAsset.unscoped returns an [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html), meaning you can call `.count, .where, .includes,` etc on it.

So the full query would be:

```
MediaFileAsset.unscoped.where(service_assset_cores: :archived).count
```

Or, you could define a named scope on `MediaFileAsset` called archived, and rescope it after you unscope it:

```
class MediaFileAsset < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :archived, { where service_asset_cores: :archived }
  # ...
end


MediaFileAsset.unscoped.archived.count
```

---

```
  def self.without_default_scope
    klass = self.dup
    klass.default_scopes = []
    klass
  end
```

Comment: I'll clarify the question: what I'm trying to do is remove the archived scope but nothing else. For example, I want to count all MediaFileAsset rows *regardless* of the archived field, but preserving any previous scopes that may have been imposed.

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz  Ah, I see. I believe unscope can only take a key-value, not a fully parsed where condition. MediaFileAsset.unscope(where: :service_asset_cores) would be the closest you could get, I think.

Comment: Yeah I fear that's the true answer, that I can't do what I'm trying to. Even your unscope suggestion doesn't seem to work, I'm still getting the count of 10 with a query that includes the archived condition. I'm paying with: klass = MediaFileAsset.dup; klass.default_scopes=[]; klass.count -- but I'm still not sure how to connect that to previous queries on an instantiated ActiveRecord::Relation obkect.

Comment: Your duplication of the class isn't a broken solution, but then you'll merge in the Relation object you get passed in? I'd be curious how you'd accomplish that.

Comment: Hm, I fear not quite as well. Doing that seems to still remove a where(id: (0..100000)) condition I put on, so I guess default_scopes= does more than I thought it would.  MediaFileAsset.where(id: (0..100000)).without_default_scope.count == MediaFileAsset.unscoped.count, where in the without_default_scope method I used klass = self.dup; klass.default_scopes=[]; self.unscoped.merge(klass.all)

Comment: I can't confirm that it strips other conditions. I used a default_scoped model in my codebase here and dup'd it and nuked the default_scope. klass.where(id: (0..1000).to_sql produces the expected (with the where clause).

Comment: Sure, but I think merging in a previous relation isn't working: klass.merge(relation) doesn't preserve conditions on relation is what I'm seeing, so I think using klass as we've defined it is no different from using unscoped.

Comment: I'm not sure if it'd be a desireable API for what you're doing, but perhaps you could define a class method on your model to strip the default scope. See the code example amended above.

Comment: Still seems to be equivalent to unscoped: MediaFileAsset.where(id: (0..100)).without_default_scope.count == MediaFileAsset.unscoped.count == 3078951. Might be as close as I can get though, thanks for all the suggestions!!

Comment: AndrewSchwartz, I just realized what you were saying here isn't quite inline with what I'd imagined. Using the without_default_scope method, I'd go about it this way: MediaFileAsset.without_default_scope.where(id: (0..100))

Comment: Quite so, but that was my hope: to build a solution that was usable like unscope(), where you could take an already defined relation and remove the default scope. Using it your way is identical to using the unscoped() method: MediaFileAsset.unscoped.where(id: (0..100)), so there's no need to go through the klass.dup acrobatics instead of just using unscoped.